# D3 .extent() rejecting array of Dates in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, d3.js, visualization

I'm struggling to utilize d3's .extent() function in typescript.

I've got some code here that creates Date objects out of dates

```
 const dates:(Date | null)[] = data.map(row => d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(row.Date))
```

When I console log the dates variable, it looks something like this

```
[Sat Jun 24 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), Sat Jun 24 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), Fri Jun 23 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), Fri Jun 23 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), Fri Jun 23 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), ...]
```

Therefore, I know my dates variable is full of Date objects, like expected...

However, when I try and use the d3.extent() function to find the highest and lowest dates

```
const xScale = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(dates))
```

```
Argument of type '[undefined, undefined] | [string, string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<Date | NumberValue>'.
```

I'm confused as to why this might be, though, as my dates variable is in fact exclusively dates, and not, as is expressed in the error, '[undefined, undefined] | [string, string]'.

What is wrong about what I am passing in? How should I be passing in dates to the extent() function in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering for `null` instances is a good approach, but you get:
`Type '(Date | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'Date[]'. Type 'Date | null' is not assignable to type 'Date'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date'`.

That is because TypeScript is still considering the possibility of `null` values in your array even after the filter operation.

You should include a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) `date is Date` in the filter function. That explicitly tells TypeScript that the result of the filter will only include `Date` objects, and no `null` values.

```js
const dates:(Date)[] = data
    .map(row => d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(row.Date))
    .filter((date): date is Date => date !== null);
```

That does create a filter function that not only checks if the date is not `null`, but also uses a type guard to tell TypeScript that every item that passes this filter is a `Date`.
(See also "**[Type predicates: Filtering arrays in Typescript](https://medium.com/devil-is-in-the-details/filtering-arrays-using-type-predicates-in-typescript-cf554afc76a3)**" from **[Shreejit Rajbanshi](https://twitter.com/shreejitrajban1)**)

The OP used:

`dates: (Date)[]`: After your filter operation (`filter((date): date is Date => date !== null)`), you ensured that all `null` values were filtered out. Thus, you're left with an array of `Date` objects only. Therefore, you need to type `dates` as `Date[]` instead of `(Date | null)[]`.

Followed with:

```js
const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dates) as unknown as [Date, Date]);
```

The original code I proposed uses `as [Date, Date]` to tell TypeScript to trust us that the domain will be a tuple of two `Date` objects.

The `as [Date, Date]` is a type assertion, it is not changing the actual value or operation of the code, but rather just informing TypeScript of the type. That will not protect you from `null` or undefined values at runtime, it is purely for TypeScript's static type checking. Hence, why we did the `null` check before during the filter operation.

But the OP used instead:

`dates as unknown as Date[]`: This construct is used when TypeScript cannot directly assert from one type to another, but we, as developers, know it's possible. By casting to `unknown` first, you essentially bypass TypeScript's type checking and then re-assert it as `Date[]`.

Comment: solution mostly worked! needed to change d3.extent(dates) as [Date, Date]) to dates as unknown as date, and needed to change dates:(Date | null)[] to dates:(Date)[], but worked after that

Comment: @Luke OK. I have edited the code in the answer accordingly. Let me know if I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: nice thanks! yeah the one that worked for me on the domain line was .domain(d3.extent(dates) as unknown as [Date, Date]) . so if you want you can edit that into your answer . but yeah after some minor changes your solution worked great! many thanks